# Writing OLE compound files with python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32, ole, bytestream

I have two bytestream, these data should be dump in a compound OLE file both together in a container. I just checked that there are some third party libraries to do it, but I would like to do it with pywin32, I have this library in my project and I would not like to add more third party libraries which maybe I could not mantain in the future. If for some reason I can not use Com objects from Windows, which is the best option or the best library?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

dI found several libraries, useless right now to create an ole object from scratch then add some streams in to the container. The only way to do it is through pywin32 then use a Com object. The problem is as always with pywin32, no examples, no a good documentation. Nice.

Does anyone would know how to do it? It would help just to know how to open a com object for this purpose.

Thanks.